# How can I safely increase the character limit for post passwords?

Tags: posts, database, password

When I want to protect a post on one of my blogs, I like to use a passphrase instead of a password (albeit purely for the sake of creativity, not [security](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/passwords-vs-pass-phrases.html) — they're stored plainly anyway). However, these passphrases often get very long, and when I enter a passphrase that's too long, it gets silently truncated to 20 characters, much to my disdain.

Looking in the `wp_posts` table, I see that the `post_password` column is a `VARCHAR(20)`. That explains the arbitrary truncation, but at the same time it raises a concern: if I want to increase the character limit so I can use longer post passwords, it would have to involve altering `wp_posts.post_password`, besides possibly overriding any validation or processing routines (which is trivial by using filter hooks).

Altering the column directly using SQL doesn't seem like a smart idea. Is there a safe way to increase the maximum character limit for post passwords, that won't cause problems with my database when it comes to things like upgrades? (Better still if I can turn this functionality into a plugin, as I don't see such a plugin available yet...)

Answer (score 0):

If its not for security, it seems odd to spend time on it. Rather ensure the password isn't truncated using a simple javascript character limit on the field and then work within the basic functionality - as you've stated, they are saved as plain text anyway. Maybe you're looking for an alternative way to protect your posts?

Comment: Perhaps I am. I'm almost tempted to protect my entire blog with a single password instead, in good ol' HTTP 401 fashion. But what would you suggest?